# 2002 Saturn SL1

Tags: clutch, cylinder, master

I have a 2002 Saturn SL1 I replaced the master cylinder the slave cylinder put a new clutch kit in it and can't get pressure on my clutch pedal and it won't go in gear

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you forgot to bleed the clutch. You have air in the system so depressing the clutch pedal is just compressing that air instead of moving the slave cylinder. Hydraulic systems have to be completely free of air to work properly.

You can try [this procedure](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/67136/44030) from an answer by Solar Mike to another question here.